# Angularjs, $http.get in Service does not update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to update my $scope.gs variable in the view using {{gs}} when I am doing http.get in the service. I tried reading some of the answers but they seem to suggest this method. Please help...

My service method is as below:

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope) {
this.getData = function(key){
    return $http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN').
    then(function(data) {       
    return data;
    });
    }
    //return this;
});
```

My controller is:

```
app.controller('graph', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService){
myService.getData($scope.mySelected).then(function(codes){
$scope.gs= codes;
});
}]);
```

I am not sure if I should use factory instead of Service for this. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 0):

possible to use `$q`

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function (key) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();

            $http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN')
                .then(function (result) {
                    deffered.resolve(result.data);
                }, function (error) {
                    deffered.reject(error);
                });

            return deferred.promise
        }
    }
});
```

or adjust your service to

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function (key) {
            $http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use then twice. Try

Service

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope) {
     this.getData = function(key){
         return $http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN');       
     });
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('graph', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService){
     myService.getData($scope.mySelected).then(function(response){
          $scope.gs= response.data;
     });
}]);
```

Comment: Hi Lukszaq, thanks for your answer. This is working but I also want to do some processing on the data in the service so that I can use it in two different controllers is there a way. Thank you again.

Comment: @sachin U can use services in as many controller as u want. Is not needed to change it.